# Magento Website stuck in arabic

Tags: magento-1, configuration, locale

I have a Magento web site stuck in displaying admin pages in Arabic language.

```
I've tried changing the language via cpanel and also via the admin pages, general etc...
```

Can anyone tell me if I can do this manually in a DB table or file as it's hard enough trying to view these pages and try to decipher the text.

Comment: Was it switched to Arabic on purpose at some point, or maybe you got hacked?

Answer (score 0):

I Just solved this way, after having changed my language locale for my admin account in one not installed (it_IT, thus I could not go back to original en_US because of no link functionality.

Follow these rules: 1) find your directory pub\static\adminhtml\Magento\backend\en_US (or original install package in your case) 2) copy all content in the other \backend directory, overwriting all.

refresh browser, done...